# I'm receiving this error when trying to debug my node application using the npm start command

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-19T04_04_31_670Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Open your package.json file, do you have a property called "start" inside the "scripts" property?

Comment: Did you run `npm init` in your command line first of all?

Comment: In my code I have 3 package.json file, I have already "start" property also

Comment: can you provide pictures, code, or whatever

Comment: You should normally just have one `package.json` file unless you're using workspaces or examples.